# UDP hole punching on IPv6

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, hole-punching

I have successfully implemented UDP hole punching in IPv4. I wrote my implementation in C using the socket/bind/sendto/recvfrom. Wikipedia provides [a good outline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching).

But when I try this same implementation with IPv6, the hole punching fails. I can see that A is sending packets to B and vice versa in an attempt to hole punch. But it seems that neither A or B is receiving those packets.

Is UDP hole punching not possible with IPv6?

NOTE: If both hosts share the same Wifi, then my hole punching is successful with IPv6. The problem occurs when they do not share the same Wifi (works for IPv4, not for IPv6).

Comment: Since IPv6 doesn't have NAT, why do you need UDP hole punching? Every IPv6 host should have a Global IPv6 address, even if it has other address types. That is the whole purpose of IPv6: every host gets a unique public IP address to restore the IP promise of end-to-end connectivity.

Comment: There's no need to post the outline from wikipedia - the content completely overshadows the question you posted.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you, I am not at all knowledgeable with regard to IPv6. Does that mean that any IPv6 host can ping any other IPv6 host using the Global IPv6 address, even those behind firewalls?  I would expect a basic firewall to prevent this, even for IPv6, no?

Comment: That depends on how the firewall is configured, but ICMP should be allowed through a firewall for IPv6 to work correctly. A host could also block ping.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thank you, my question looks much cleaner now.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you. So with ICMP going through a firewall, shouldn't my hosts A and B receive the others' hole punch attempts? I understand you're saying that hole punching shouldn't be necessary for IPv6. But shouldn't my hole punch attempts be received by the other, particularly since I know this works with IPv4. Also, when I put both of my hosts on the same IPv6 Wifi, the hole punch is successful. Amending my question with this note.

Comment: You are probably blocking ICMPv6 on the firewall, but for IPv6, you really shouldn't block ICMPv6. It really depends on how you have your firewall configured.

Comment: @RonMaupin I don't think that's the case. I have tried the case where one of my nodes is an iOS app running on IPv6 Cellular, not through Wifi. The result is the same. Both nodes send a number of hole punch attempts, but neither appears to receive them.

Comment: "a good outline" - still the cook book text: The holes are punched with sending packets to the mediator server "S"